# Update dockerfile image without downloading dependencies

Tags: java, docker, debian

I am new to docker. I use an image debian to host a J2EE application.

```
FROM debian

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get --assume-yes install \
    default-jre \
    default-jdk \
    maven

RUN mvn clean install

CMD ["mvn", "ninja:run"]
```

I build my image by doing this:

`docker build . -t rssaggregator`

Let's suppose I add a new dependency to download. How can I update and build the image without downloading the dependencies again?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you add the dependencies in separate RUN statements *after* your primary installs (and don't change any of the Dockerfile above that), Docker will used cached layers and won't download the unmodified layers unless you specify --no-cache in your build (which you may want to do at some point if you want to update your primary installs/layers).

You also may want to specify the version of the JRE and JDK installs so you know which it's using and then you can change those versions to make updating easier.

See [dockerfile_best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/). You may also want to try a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) for a more advanced approach on building on a base image.